# GAE dev server ignoring request module version?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, webob

Having the following entry in the libraries section of my app.yaml:

```
- name: webob
  version: "1.2.3"
```

When I execute the following code

```
import webob
print webob.__file__
```

I get `/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.1.1/webob/__init__.py` even though `/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3/webob/__init__.py` is readily available.

Furthermore, digging a little bit into [the code](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_import_hook.py#1128) it seems that the requested library versions are ignored for everything but Django.

Is this how it's supposed to be? Shouldn't it actually import the request version?

This is with the 1.8.3 dev server.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will respect it when deployed.. while locally it might fail.. even though it should make sense to be able to test locally as well..

Comment: Thanks, confirmed that in production it uses the correct version. Will fill a bug for this.

Comment: Added issue https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9867

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is fixed now: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9867